# The mouse pointer in i3 is half the size it should be. How to make it bigger?

Tags: xorg, mouse, i3

I've followed the Arch Wiki HiDPI guides for configuring my HiDPI system for i3. In ~/.xinitrc I have:

```
xrandr --dpi 192
```

But my mouse pointer is half the size it should be. What can I do to make it bigger?

Comment: Does the mouse pointer have the expected size on screen if you run `xrandr --dpi 96`?

Comment: Nope, it's still tiny.