# i3 font size changed after Space got stuck

Tags: x11, window-manager, i3

I'm using `Arch 5.14.12-arch1-1` with `i3` as the window manager. The other day, while browsing in Firefox, I did something trivial (like changing a Firefox tab or jumping to another i3 workspace or just typing) and all of a sudden my computer started spamming the Space character as if I held it down. I tried pressing it a couple of times to try to get anything unstuck, but nothing was stuck in the first place. Since each keystroke of mine now contained Space along with the actual keystroke, all my i3 shortcuts were broken.

I managed to click on another workspace with another window (Telegram), and it didn't go away. I wanted to restart i3, but I effectively didn't have a keyboard anymore, so I had no choice but to forcibly shut down the computer. Once I restarted, the issue was thankfully resolved.

However, it seems I did something in that whole ordeal: everything in i3 got very large: my `i3bar` and tab/window names' font size, the circular typing indicator of `i3exit lock`. I went through i3 and i3blocks config files, and I cannot see anything related to size has changed, nor did I see any binding related to font size which might have been inadvertently triggered.

So I have 2 questions:

- What could have caused the Space spamming thing?
- What could have caused the enlarging of i3 and how can I revert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether this is related, `archi7 5.14.16-arch1-1`, but the scaling on my `i3` bar and window frames did the same after an update earlier this week. Was resolved by putting

```
xrandr --dpi 96
```

in my `~/.xinitrc` and a reboot. For the `i3` stuff it may be enough to just restart it in-place but for me, like OP, it was not persistent across boots.

Never did get to the root of the "why".

**Edit**

Untried by me but a similar mouse sizing issue is reported on [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420427/the-mouse-pointer-in-i3-is-half-the-size-it-should-be-how-to-make-it-bigger) and a possible solution put forward in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/3xmfpi/mouse_pointer_is_huge_when_not_inside_a_window/cy7tmbc/) with reference to the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Cursor_themes#X_resources)

Comment: Hm. That didn't work for me. I also tried other DPI values, with no effect. But thanks for your input - it hadn't occured to me that this might have something to do with xrandr! I'll check back if I find something relevant out.

Comment: We can but try. I found that amending any of the i3 configs which had no effect and simply concluded it was external to `i3`. Experimentation led me to my solution. It's odd that changing dpi has no effect because it should. Maybe investigate [what is setting it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi)

Comment: Setting the DPI and rebooting did nothing for me because `xrandr`'s result apparently doesn't persist across reboots, and I didn't try restarting i3 in-place (`$mod+Shift+r` by default). I now tried setting the DPI and restarting i3, and it worked: i3bar font size and the i3exit lock thingy size are back to what they were! My mouse cursor is still quite huge, though.

I'll investigate what sets the DPI to the higher value (160, according to `xdpyinfo`) and try to persist it across reboots. After that, we can edit your answer to contain the whole solution, and then I'll accept it.